# How to write a script to change BIOS settings

Tags: retropie, pi-zero-w

So I'm following a tutorial to make a retro gaming console out of an old NES controller (e.g. http://www.instructables.com/id/RetroPie-Inside-an-NES-Controller/).  I have the controller already configured and set up correctly.  To configure the controller I need to go through a BIOS program to select some options then add some text to a file.

Rather than repeat these steps whenever I want to configure a controller, is there a way to write a script to do this?  I can write a script to add text to the file no problem but `my question is can you write a script to open BIOS and select specific options from the menus within?`

Comment: What BIOS the Pi doesn't really have one in the traditional sense and what it does have isn't pdateable https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/what-bios-does-raspberry-pi-use

Comment: Well it's the retro pie BIOS (e.g. http://www.babuleando.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Actualizar-MAME-en-RetroPie-00.png).  For example, say I wanted to write a script to open raspi-config,  go to interfacing options, then enable SSH, as opposed to doing it manually.  Is something like that possible?

Comment: possible, but not the easiest method/ If you look at raspi-config all it does is call out to other system functions and scripts. It would be far easier to call the same scripts with the appropriate parameters. You also may want to edit your question and mention raspi-config not bios. also, if you have enough Pi's to do this too wouldn't it be easier to manually make all the changes then backup the SD card image. With only a single computer I fail to see the ROI.

Comment: great point.  Why go through the interface (i.e. raspi-config) to turn SSH on when I can just figure out wherever raspi-config is reading it from and operate on it from there.

Comment: IIRC if all you want to do is enable SSH you can just drop an empty ssh file in the /boot directory.